# mysql 5.7 geospatial for geolocation distance query

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I'm attempting to get my head around geospatial indexes in mysql and I'm having trouble getting simple queries to work and I think it's down to my lack of understanding. I'm basically trying to get a number of locations within a 10 mile radius of a lat/lon I pass in.

The table structure is very simple

Points:
name (varchar)
location (Point)

at present there's only one row
name - "point1"  location:POINT(31.5 42.2)

Now I'm trying the following sql that I've lifted from here https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/

```
set @lat= 31.5;
set @lon = 42.2;
set @dist = 10;
set @rlon1 = @lon-@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69); 
set @rlon2 = @lon+@dist/abs(cos(radians(@lat))*69); 
set @rlat1 = @lat-(@dist/69); 
set @rlat2 = @lat+(@dist/69);

select astext(location), name from Points 
where st_contains(location, envelope(linestring(point(@rlon1, @rlat1), point(@rlon2, @rlat2))))  
order by st_distance(point(@lon, @lat), location) limit  10;
```

but it returns an empty result set. Anyone got any ideas or pointers? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working

I was assuming a 'Point' object was lat,lon but it's not as far as I can tell it's lon,lat. So in theory the problem was I had stored my initial 'Point' coordinate values the wrong way round in the table even though I thought the standard way was lat/lon